# node js регистрация

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

js

```
const requestUrl = 'localhost' //node js работает на 3000 порте его нужно записать именно на 3000? или выдать просто localhos? 
let login = document.querySelector('.login');
let password = document.querySelector('.password');
let info = document.querySelector('.submit');

function sendRequest(method,url,body = null){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type:','application/json');
      xhr.open('POST',url);
      xhr.onload = () =>{
         if(xhr.status >= 400){
            reject(xhr.response);
         }else{
            resolve(xhr.response);
         }
            
      }
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(body));
   });
}

info.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   let body = {
      login: `${JSON.stringify(login.value)}`,
      password: `${JSON.stringify(login.value)}`
   }
   sendRequest('POST',requestUrl,body)
   .then(data =>console.log(data))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

в общем объясните мне пошагово как правильно отправить ajax запрос на node js что бы он принял его и оббработал. Нужно ли в форме html записывать путь к файлу?(да,очень сложно для меня, не могу разобраться), а после записал в бд. Я не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста, работать с mongodb пока не буду, хочу разобраться с sql.

Comment: Никакой `requestUrl=localhost` не нужен. Сегодня это один порт, завтра другой, а после завтра это имя домена. На текущий домен, в том числе и с портом, запрос отправляется как `/` или если это путь `/path?param=123`

Comment: ...и да, пора бы использовать [fetch('/path')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)

Answer (score 0):

```
const requestUrl = 'localhost'
```

вы просто не добавили PORT

```
const requestUrl = 'localhost:3000'
```

Т.К. у вас сервер на 3000 порте работает надо дописать порт